# How to make Boolean parameter disable depending on other parameter values?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have two text box parameter i made them Null by default. And i have one Boolean parameter. I want to make Boolean parameter disabled if the other two text box parameter are not Null.I tried this expression but don't know syntax is correct or not

```
=iff(Parameters!CvrgEffDt.Value = "" Or Parameters!CvrgExpDt.Value = "").disabled
```

Comment: By disabled you mean false ?

Comment: Yes, he is not able to select true or if true is selected make it false.

Comment: I have tired what you have suggested. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
 =IIF(Parameters!CvrgEffDt.Value <> NOTHING AND Parameters!CvrgExpDt.Value <> NOTHING,False,True)
```

It should be your default value **expression** of the boolean parameter

Comment: I applied this it makes it grey out and user is not able to select any thing

Comment: It works here like a charm, check your expression, I use for test : 
IIF(1=1,true,false), it shows true on runtime

Comment: By default they are set to Null

Comment: As in : No default value ? or specify values -> (NULL) ? try both approaches, try with a specified value first instead of NULL to Ensure that the problem is there

Comment: I have removed the default value from Null i am getting same results.

Comment: send me your RDL, Simco_admin@Hotmail.com

Comment: It works properly with the following expression : =IIF(Parameters!CvrgEffDt.Value = NOTHING OR Parameters!CvrgExpDt.Value = NOTHING,false,true)  , BUT if the boolean parameter is visible, it doesnt switch values in the parameter list. When you make this parameter internal, the result will work as I have shown in the RDL that I have send you bu showing the value in the report. Since this value depends on other parameters I do not see the necessity of showing it to user. It should be either giving the user a choice OR setting it up based on other parameters programmatically.